# Error in specifying game over text function

Tags: python, pygame

I defined a function game over to display game over text on the screen :-

## This is the function

```
def game_over():
    over_text = font.render("Game Over", True, (255, 2555, 255))
    window.blit(over_text, (400, 600))
```

## Here I have ordered it to execute

```
if collision:
    game_over()
```

Errors

(1) line 214, in `enter code here`
game_over()
(2) line 129, in game_over
over_text = font.render("Game Over", True, (255, 2555, 255))

```
    ValueError: invalid color argument
```

Comment: The 2nd color element is 2555. Should be 255

Answer (score 2):

2555 is an invalid color element.

Comment: Yeah, I know this is a very silly mistake. I realized it myself soon after posting this but still Thank You